# Combine multiple search options into one in MongoDB and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

Having this working code:

```
const aggregateOptions = [];

// search by name
if (req.query.name) {
  aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } } });
}

// search by surname
if (req.query.surname) {
  aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { surname: req.query.surname } });
}

// search by nationality
if (req.query.nationality) {
  aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { nationality: req.query.nationality } });
}
```

It is responsible for building a query for searching. The problem is that they work separately and I want to be able to write a string into the search bar and the code to search through all 3 fields.

For example, how it is now there is a search bar for name and when I write "my_string" it checks only if there is a name="my_string" and I want to check for all of them.

Something like name="my_string" OR surname="my_string" OR nationality="my_string".

So I used $or and wrote this:

```
  aggregateOptions.push({
      $or: [
        { nationality: req.query.nationality },
        { surname: req.query.surname },
        { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
      ],
    });
```

which seem to be wrong and returns this error message: **"$or is not allowed in this atlas tier"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use text search for this. In mongo you can make a text index with nationality, surname and name, with something like

```
db.collection.createIndex( { nationality: "text", surname: "text", name: "text" } )
```

Now you can query your collection with something like

```
db.collection.find({$text: { $search:req.query.name } })
```

Which will perform a text search on all 3 fields and return any matches.

Here are some resources:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/
Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried it and it says that `db is not defined`. How should it be defined?

Comment: The first command (createIndex) should be done within the database. It will create an index that is searchable, and then the find() will have to be done within your code depending on what driver you're using. https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/ Check out the links I've posted or look up guides to see how to set it up.